# Grid Clipping- Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, xaml

```
<Grid Height="333">
    <Canvas Margin="0,-41">
        <Rectangle Height="60" Width="72" Canvas.Left="73" Canvas.Top="355">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="None" ImageSource="aaa.png"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

The problem is Rectangle is visible out of the Grid and I don't want this.
What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to clip the Grid. I wrote an attached property that will do this for you. See the following blog post:

http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2009/05/silverlight-cliptobounds-can-i-clip-it-yes-you-can/

You can use it as follows:

```
<Grid Height="333" util:Clip.ToBounds="true">
    <Canvas Margin="0,-41">
        <Rectangle Height="60" Width="72" Canvas.Left="73" Canvas.Top="355">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="None" ImageSource="aaa.png"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Internally this attached behaviour sets the `FrameworkElement.Clip` property to the required geometry based on the current size of the element it is attached to.